Docker with WSL2 and Nvidia throwing sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found
I am on Windows 10 and am trying to run a few docker containers to handle CARLA, ROS, the bridge between the two, and visualization. The ROS and visualization containers build without issue, the bridge builds fine, but fails on run as it relies on CARLA, and then the CARLA server itself fails with: sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found.
carla.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  # Carla server container
  carla:
    image: carlasim/carla:0.9.15
    container_name: carla
    runtime: nvidia
    ports: 2000-2002:2000-2002
    command: ["bash", "-c", "./CarlaUE4.sh -vulkan -nosound -RenderOffscreen"]

Which will return with the failure:
carla      | sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found
carla exited with code 1

I have tried going into the container as root and installing xdg-user-dirs and xdg-utils, with no success.
